# jQuery/javascript Plugin for maps that will render borders or parks

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, gis, built-in

I am searching for a jQuery plugin that should be able to implement park border layers from Google Earth or where ever I can find such data free. I am basically looking for advice as I am new to using any kind of map GIS plug-in. I would like to know if any do which would be able to render a layer such as this on it that would depict perhaps location point, borders (based on a category or selection like state land or parks boundaries), and allow me to raster or inlay an image possibly (but not necessarily.)

If you have some suggestions on built in javascript/jQuery GIS maps please let me know.